# Implementing many to many relationship in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hello i have an application that contains a basic user profile such as firstname, lastname and email. users can create an event. The event table includes a title, description, time of event. A user can create an event and invite others to join that event. Also a user can be invited to multiple events.

Analysis: This is a many to many relationship since a user can have multiple events and events can be created by multiple users. From my analysis i can do this in 2 ways.

1. Have a friendship table by adding users to the friends table and inviting them to the event and await a confirmation request from friends. OR
2. Just have a user create an event and broadcast to all users in the user table and await a confirmation request from each user.

I went with number 2. I created a user table and an event table. Since it's a many to many relationship created another table called `user_event`. `user_event` table contains the event, the userA who owns the event and userB are users attending the event. I added another column called pending_request with a default value of 0 indicating not attending and 1 means attending. For some reason i feel my approach is wrong, please could someone correct me on my approach and if my schema is wrong.

Event table:

```
create table if not exist 'event'(
event_id unsigned unsigned int not null auto_increment,
title varchar(20) not null,
description varchar(20) not null,
date dateTime not null,
primary key(event_id))ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

User Table:

```
create table if not exist 'user'(
  user_id unsigned int not null auto_increment,
  firstName varchar(20) not null,
  lastName varchar(20) not null,
  image varchar(20) not null,
  primary key(user_id))ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Many to Many relationship between user and event:

```
create table if not exist 'users_event'(
   event_id unsigned not null,
   userA unsigned not null,
   userB unsigned not null,
   pending_request int not null default 0,
   Foreign Key(event_id) references event(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   Foreign Key(userA) references event(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   Foreign Key(userB) references event(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE))ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Not to say it isn't wrong, but that looks like approximately how I'd do it.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax so i'm on the right track.